# WPF efficient drawing in usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, naudio

I have a performance issue drawing a usercontrol in WPF. Here is what I do. 
Basically the application plays an audio file. The class playing the audio file sends information about its position every few times a second.

I have a Usercontrol that renders the position of the file. I do it like this:

```
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {

        // lots of drawing happens here like drawingContext.DrawRectangle,
        // drawingContext.DrawLine ....

        base.OnRender(drawingContext);
    }
```

Now I have another thread in the application that does some processing (basically reading audio data) and sends information to the usercontrol afew times every second via delegate. The second process declares a delegate like this:

```
    protected virtual void OnBytesPlayed(BytesPlayedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (playheadCallback != null)
            playheadCallback(fileStream.CurrentTime.TotalSeconds, fileStream.TotalTime.TotalSeconds);

    }
```

the usercontrol registered to that event and redraws itself as such:

```
    public void PlayheadPositionUpdate(double currentFrame, double allFrames)
    {

        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
           DispatcherPriority.Background,
           new System.Action(() =>
           {
               this.InvalidateVisual();
           }));
    }
```

This all works, however once I enable the callback and it draws the usercontrol a few times every second everything becomes sluggish and performance goes down. So I guess the way I handle the drawing or redrawing is not efficient. Can someone point me in the right direction how to redraw the usercontrol so it does not impact the playback performance or the overall performance of the application?

Please let me know if I need to explain more or provide more code. I wanted to keep it as simple as possible to outline the problem.

thank you.

Edit:

The code that calls NAudio is

```
            var inputStream = new AudioFileReader(filename);

            fileStream = inputStream;

            var aggregator = new SampleAggregator(inputStream);

            aggregator.NotificationCount = inputStream.WaveFormat.SampleRate;

            aggregator.BytesPLayed += (s, a) => OnBytesPlayed(a);

            playbackDevice.Init(aggregator);
```

Comment: On what thread are you playing the audio?

Comment: I am using a library called naudio. Not sure how its implemented in detail but assume seperate thread since the rest of the main screen minus usercontrol reacts properly. Problem only comes in when i redraw the user control several times a second.

Comment: As far as i remember it does matter how you are using NAudio. Just search for NAudio and thread and you'll find discussions on this. Could you add the code that initializes and starts NAuio?

Comment: A probably more efficient way to draw into a DrawingVisual would be to use it like shown in the [Using DrawingVisual Objects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742254.aspx) article on MSDN (with a DrawingVisual Host Container). It would eliminate the need for calling InvalidateVisual, which according to MSDN, "forces a complete new layout pass".

Comment: You could also draw your bitmap outside in a separate thread... And only invalidate when the drawing is done... The invalidation should then push the bitmap directly on your canvas... 

If you have some basic draws then you could even cache them in another bitmap, and only redraw the dynamic data :=)

Comment: Hi Erno. I edited the original post to see how I call NAudio. Thanks for your help. I will definitely look into threading NAudio to make sure this is not the cause of the issue here.

Comment: Thanks Clements and Laurent for your comments. I will look into your suggestions. I was also wondering if there is a more efficient way to redraw without redrawing the whole usercontrol each time.

Comment: Hi Erno, sure enough the way I was using NAudio was not right. I changed using WaveOutEvent to make sure it runs in its own thread. Thanks for your help. Next is optimizing the rendering trying some methods Clemens and Laurent suggested. thanks yall. I am on the right path I feel.

Answer (score 3):

You should use data binding and INotifyPropertyChanged instead and let the framework control the rendering. I have a simple example to show how display a simple graph.
[image]

**GraphControl.xaml**

```
  <Border Height="50" Width="200" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="1" BorderThickness="0.1">
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas" Background="White" Margin="0" ClipToBounds="True" />
  </Border>
```

**GraphControl.xaml.cs**

```
  public partial class GraphControl : UserControl
  {
    public IEnumerable<double> Data
    {
      get { return (IEnumerable<double>)GetValue(DataProperty); }
      set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(IEnumerable<double>), typeof(GraphControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnDataChanged));

    private static void OnDataChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
      var control = (GraphControl)dependencyObject;
      control.HandleDataChanged();
    }

    public Brush Color
    {
      get { return (Brush)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
      set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Color", typeof(Brush), typeof(GraphControl), new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.Green));

    public double Maximum
    {
      get { return (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
      set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(GraphControl), new PropertyMetadata(100.0));

    private void HandleDataChanged()
    {
      var points = new PointCollection();
      double x = 0;


      points.Add(new Point(0, canvas.ActualHeight));


      var xScale = canvas.ActualWidth / (Data.Count() -1);
      var yScale = canvas.ActualHeight / Maximum;
      foreach (var dataPoint in Data)
      {
        var y = canvas.ActualHeight - dataPoint * yScale;

        points.Add(new Point(x,y));
        x += xScale;

      }

      points.Add(new Point(canvas.ActualWidth, canvas.ActualHeight));

      var fill = Color.Clone();
      fill.Opacity = 0.2;
      polygon.Stroke = Color;
      polygon.Fill = fill;

      polygon.Points = points;

    }

    Polygon polygon = new Polygon() ;

    public GraphControl()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      var fill = Color.Clone();
      fill.Opacity = 0.2;
      polygon.Stroke = Color;
      polygon.Fill = fill;

      polygon.StrokeThickness = 1;

      canvas.Children.Add(polygon);
    }
  }
```

And for testing...
**MainWindows.xaml**

```
  DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
  <StackPanel >
    <simpleGraph:GraphControl Data="{Binding Data}" Margin="4" />
    <simpleGraph:GraphControl Data="{Binding Data}" Margin="4" />
    <simpleGraph:GraphControl Data="{Binding Data}" Margin="4" />
    <simpleGraph:GraphControl Data="{Binding Data}" Margin="4" />
    <simpleGraph:GraphControl Data="{Binding Data}" Margin="4" />
    <simpleGraph:GraphControl Data="{Binding Data}" Margin="4" />
    <simpleGraph:GraphControl Data="{Binding Data}" Margin="4" />
  </StackPanel>
```

**MainWindows.xaml.cs**

```
private Random random = new Random();

public List<double> Data { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  var temp = new List<double>();
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    temp.Add(random.NextDouble() * 100);
  }
  Data = new List<double>(temp);
  RaisePropertyChanged("Data");

  Timer timer = new Timer(1);
  timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
  {
    UpdateData();
  };
  timer.Start();
}

private void UpdateData()
{
  var data = Data.ToArray();
  ShiftLeft(data, 1);


  var value = random.NextDouble() * 100;
  data[99] = value;

  Data = new List<double>(data); 

  RaisePropertyChanged("Data");
}

public void ShiftLeft<T>(T[] array, int shifts)
{
  Array.Copy(array, shifts, array, 0, array.Length - shifts);
  Array.Clear(array, array.Length - shifts, shifts);
}

private void RaisePropertyChanged(string property)
{
  if (PropertyChanged != null)
    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

It´s very crude but hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to call `InvalidateVisual()` as this causes a very slow re-layout of the UI. However you also don't need to use DataBinding (though it is a good solution).

To make the method you are trying to use fast, create a DrawingGroup "backingStore" to hold your drawing commands. In your OnRender() method, output the DrawingGroup to the DrawingContext. Then you can update the backingStore whenever you like and your visuals will be updated. Move your existing rendering code to a different "Render()" method that just draws into the backingStore.

The code looks like this:

```
DrawingGroup backingStore = new DrawingGroup();

protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext) {      
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);            

    Render(); // put content into our backingStore
    drawingContext.DrawDrawing(backingStore);
}

// I can call this anytime, and it'll update my visual drawing
// without ever triggering layout or OnRender()
private void Render() {            
    var drawingContext = backingStore.Open();
    Render(drawingContext);
    drawingContext.Close();            
}
```